# Lookup and join text gives zero instead of blank

Tags: excel, join, text, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup values based on two simple criterias.

Here is my formula:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(". ";TRUE;IF(F1=A2:A6;IF(F2=B2:B6;C2:C6;"");""))}
```

[image]

However, I get `0` in the middle of the text join. How can I ignore values in `Text` when it is actually empty or blank and get expected value of `One. Two. Three. Five` instead of `One. Two. Three. 0. Five`, where cell `B5` is ignored and blank.

Comment: which version of excel are you using ? I have tried the same example in Excel 15.4 for mac and it is working as expected. Formula used - `=TEXTJOIN(". ", TRUE, IF(F1=A2:A6, IF(F2=B2:B6, C2:C6, ""), ""))`. Kindly, recheck the formula as well.

Comment: @stud3nt I am using Excel 2016. My formula is an array formula. Do you get the same result with Shift + Ctrl?

Comment: Just added an answer using array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely logical. It's just not as you intended it to work. Both `IF` conditions are `TRUE` and the next thing you tell the formula to return `C2:C6` values. Therefore the `IF` returns a zero (you should use the evaluate formulas option to see what's going on), and therefore no longer an empty cell in a range, but a zero in an array. The `TRUE` parameter in the `TEXTJOIN` is therefor no longer helping you. To overcome this you could try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(". ",TRUE,IF((A2:A6=F1)*(B2:B6=F2)*(C2:C6<>""),C2:C6,""))
```

> <sub>**Note:** It's an array formula and need to be confirmed through
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd></sub>

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I get `#VALUE!` when the strings in Text is too long. Is it possible to adjust for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using array formula as below to get the desired result. Place the `TEXTJOIN` inside `IF`.

```
=IF(F1=A2:A6, IF(F2=B2:B6, TEXTJOIN(". ", TRUE, C2:C6), ""), "")
```